# How to register a background sync from my Flutter PWA dart code

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, background-sync

I am relatively new to Flutter and I am creating a PWA with it. Flutter pretty much does a lot in getting you started but I would like to add a background sync. I know how to listen to the 'sync' event in the service worker. I just don't know how/where to register a background sync from my Flutter(Dart) code. Kindly help.